# Routing is disabled for LAN users while choosing all-net for IPSec tunnel

Tags: networking, vpn, subnet, l2tp

I have VPN with L2TP/IPSec server and tunnel configured. When I choose all-nets 0.0.0.0/0 to allow connection from any computer in the world, all LAN users with subnet 10.0.0.0/8 are disconnected from internet. How can I exclude local subnet from being listed in all-net?

Comment: Is it Cisco VPN?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's D-Link NetDefend OS

Comment: Well the issue may still be the same. In Cisco world it is called split tunnelling. It basically tells the VPN client not to route all the traffic through the tunnel, but to retain local routing. This might be it. Since I don't know how to set it on your type of VPN I can't help you :)